# erasing dots from map pacman java

Tags: java, swing, collision, pacman

I'm coding my pacman, already have pacman move, loading map from txt, and collision with walls. Next step is dot eraser when pacman is on a dot field. I need any suggestion how to do it, I've tried to erase it by paiting dot at the same color as background, but it doesnt work. here is the code

board.java

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private Timer timer;
    private Map m;
    private Player p;

    public Board(){
        m = new Map();
        p = new Player();
        addKeyListener(new Klawa());
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setFocusable(true);
        timer = new Timer(25, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);

    for(int x=0; x<14; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<14; y++){
            if(m.getMap(x,y).equals("s")){
                g.drawImage(m.getWall(),x *32,y *32, this);
            }
            if(m.getMap(x,y).equals("k")){
                g.drawImage(m.getDot(),x *32,y *32, this);
            }                 
        }
    }

    g.drawImage(p.getPlayer(),p.getTileX()* 32 ,p.getTileY() * 32,null);

    }

    public void erase(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
        if(m.getMap(p.getTileX(),p.getTileY()).equals("k")){            
            g.drawImage(m.getErase(),p.getTileX(),p.getTileY(), this);
        }
    }            



    public class Klawa extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            int keycode = e.getKeyCode();

            if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_W){
                if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX(),p.getTileY() - 1).equals("s")){                    
                    p.move(0, -1);                  
                    }
                }           
            if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX(),p.getTileY() + 1).equals("s")){
                    p.move(0, 1);
                }
            }
            if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX() - 1,p.getTileY()).equals("s")){                                   
                    p.move(-1, 0);
                }
            }
            if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX() + 1,p.getTileY() ).equals("s")){
                p.move(1, 0);  
                }
            }                        
        }
        public void keyRelased(KeyEvent e){

        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

        }


    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

       repaint();
    }
}
```

map.java

```
public class Map {

    private Scanner m;
    private String Map[] = new String[16];
    private Image wall, dot, erase;

    public Map(){

       wall = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Kotek\\Desktop\\pacman\\sciana.png").getImage();
       dot = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Kotek\\Desktop\\pacman\\kropka.png").getImage();
       erase = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Kotek\\Desktop\\pacman\\wymaz.png").getImage();
       openFile();
       readFile();
       closeFile();
    }

    public Image getWall(){
        return wall;
    }

    public Image getDot(){
        return dot;
    }

    public Image getErase(){
        return erase;
    }


    public String getMap(int x, int y){
       String index = Map[y].substring(x, x+1);
       return index;     
    }

    public void openFile(){
       try{
           m = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Kotek\\Desktop\\pacman\\mapa.txt"));
       }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
           System.out.println("Blad podczas ladowania mapy");
       }
    }
    public void readFile(){
       while(m.hasNext()){
           for(int i=0; i<14; i++){
               Map[i] = m.next();
           }
       }
    }
    public void closeFile(){
       m.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class Map you should implement method

```
public void setMap(int x, int y, String  value ){
   //remove the "k" from the string
}
```

In the erase() method just clean model's cell and call `repaint()`